# Почему это работает, а это - нет?

Tags: java, static

Почему это компилируется???

```
class A {
    static {
        i = 8;
    }
    static int i = 6;
}
```

А вот это - нет.

```
class A {
    static {
        i = 8;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    static int i = 6;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624919/illegal-forward-reference-java-issue) та же самая проблема.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пожалуй, переведу [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624919/illegal-forward-reference-java-issue) статью с англоязычного *so*.

При компиляции вашего кода вылетает (наверняка) ошибка `illegal forward reference`. Дело в том, что при инициализации полей на их использование в данном случае накладываются некоторые ограничения.

Вы не можете использовать имя вашей переменной **с правой стороны выражения**, т.е. читать ее значение, однако вполне можете что-то в нее записывать.

Обойти это можно двумя способами:

1. Поместить объявление переменной до статического блока

   ```
   class A {
       static int i = 6;
       static {
           i = 8;
           System.out.println(i);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Или использовать полное имя переменной

   ```
   class A {
       static {
           i = 8;
           System.out.println(A.i);
       }
       static int i = 6;
   }
   ```

Ограничения связаны с тем, что блоки инициализации и инициализация переменных при объявлении производятся друг за другом, в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в коде. Но (если я не ошибаюсь) когда вы пытаетесь записать в переменную значение в блоке инициализации, который встречается до объявления самой переменной, то `Java` делает вид, что переменная уже объявлена, и после выполняет с переменной все необходимые действия. В этом можно убедиться, выполнив такой код:

```
public class A {
    static {
        i = 8;
        System.out.println(A.i);
    }
    static int i = 6;

    public static void main(String args[]) {}
}
```

На выходе вы увидите `8`.